# Azure account shows on web interface but not in command-line interface

Tags: azure

I got a new subscription on Azure with resource group `PB`. I can see it on the Azure portal, but it does not show with the command-line:

```
$ az account list --output table
Name                                  CloudName    SubscriptionId                        State    IsDefault
------------------------------------  -----------  ------------------------------------  -------  -----------
```

and so I cannot create virtual machines on it:

```
$az_cmd="az vm create
       --resource-group PB
       --name PBVM
       --image microsoft-dsvm:linux-data-science-vm-ubuntu:linuxdsvmubuntu:19.04.00
       --size Standard_F4s_v2
       --admin-username ${USER}"
$result=$($az_cmd)
error retrieving default location: Resource group 'PB' could not be found.
```

I tried forcing the account with `az account set --subscription "<subscription-name>"` and `az account set --subscription "<subscription-id>"` to no avail.

How can I force the CLI to see this new subscription?

Answer (score 5):

The key is to refresh the account list, as [hinted in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest):

> `az account list [--all]
>                   [--refresh]
>                   [--subscription]`
>
> ...
>
> `--refresh`
>
> ```
> Retrieve up-to-date subscriptions from server.
> ```

The result is that the new subscription becomes available locally through the command-line:

```
$ az account list --refresh
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": ...
    ...
    }
  },
  ...
]
$ az account list --output table
Name                                  CloudName    SubscriptionId                        State    IsDefault
------------------------------------  -----------  ------------------------------------  -------  -----------
new account                           AzureCloud                                         Enabled  Default
```

If this is a second subscription, you need to change it to the default with `az account set -s <subscription-name-or-id>`, else you will get the same error `Resource group 'PB' could not be found.`.